# shutil copy2 error in python | formulas replaced by 0s in an excel workbook after copy

Tags: python, excel, copy

I am getting a messy error. I have an excel worksheet which I am trying to copy from one directory to another using the below code:

```py
file = 'C:/Users/file_name.xlsx'
dst_path = 'C:/Users/xlsx_cp_dir/'
filename = os.path.basename(file)
if filename.endswith('xlsx'):
   output_file = dst_file_path + filename
   shutil.copy2(file, output_file)
   outfile_list.append(output_file)
```

When I execute the python code the excel workbook gets copied to the location but with all formulas gone and replaced by 0s. But if I run a normal cp command, it copies the exact file. I tried all possible python commands shutil, os but in vain.

Where am I going wrong ?

input:

[image]

output:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `shutil.copy()`? Both `copy` and `copy2` work well on my pc. Do you forget assign value for `dst_file_path`.  btw, you can use dest directory name as the 2nd parameter `shutil.copy2(file, dst_path)`. But this can't affect your formulas.

Comment: yes I have tried shutil.copy()

Comment: Its strange that the output timestamp is _before_ the input. Are you in the Central Time Zone? The file sizes are quite different too. For debug, you could check if the destination exists before the copy. Print full path names plus file timestamps and size. Now you have a trace of what happened and can rule out some copy-to-the-wrong-place situation.